# Magento with ElasticSearch index

Tags: magento2, reindex, elasticsearch

I'm trying to understand the "**We can't find products matching the selection**" issue that happens a few times a week with the Magento.

Most of the time(80%), this is resolved automatically in 2 minutes.

But sometimes, it needs manual intervention to run the index from the command line.

I have worked with ES(non-m2 project) previously that processes billions of records every day and have an idea of how it works.

So definitely, the scale is not the issue as the m2 website has 6k products and the document count in the index is around 6k. The CPU usage is around 5-10% at any point.

This article tried helping understand how Magento uses ES - https://orba.co/how-does-elasticsearch-work-with-magento/

What I don't understand is, why Magento keeps renaming the index name?

example: websitename_product_1_**v2687**

Does Magento really take 2 minutes to send all those 6k products? Is it that bad?

I remember we could send 20k products in less than 10 seconds via batch operation.

Trying to understand what I'm missing and to know more about the M2 way.

Thanks